# bad_utf8_character_code in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I just imported a database to couchDB to try it out. Unfortunately it seems there is some bad characters are got into my documents, so I can not create any view. Considering the large amount of data, I cann't examine the documents one by one. Can somebody tell me please how can   I identify the bad documents?

thanks

---

I tried to convert it to UTF-8 with

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = json.getBytes("UTF8");
value = new String(utf8Bytes,"UTF-8");
```

But couchdb still complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I solved the problem. It was not actually the source that had bad characters. It was the http PUT command. The only thing I added is the proper UTF-8 header. charset=UTF-8

Comment: You need to add a header like Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us a bit more information?

Are you importing the data from a text file? Another db?

Be glad to help, just don't really know where to start. :-)

Comment: I imported data from a vendors database. I don't know what other information I can provide. There are 122,000 rows so I cannot go through all of them. I am looking for a tool to tell me what character is broken and where.

Comment: @arash I've run into this problem importing data from .xls files or from databases that have been adultrated with that annoying "backwards" double quote that MS Word sticks everywhere. :-) Basically what you have to do is parse each row of the file before you add it to couchdb and attempt to convert it to utf-8 or whatever you prefer. What is your import script written in?

Comment: Thank you. I hoped that couchDB could do that for me! :) It is written in Java.

Comment: it was written in Java. Can you use a regex class to delete these characters?